# SQL query results into php table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to place the results of a SQL query into a table for my wordpress site.

My table is called "statetable"

The columns are "State", "num-Asn" , and "Percent"

The following is my code in my custom php template.

```
   global $wpdb;
   $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM statetable;");

   echo "<table>";
   foreach($results as $result){
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$result->State."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$result->num-ASN."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$result->Percent."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
    echo "</table>";


    ?>
```

I get an empty table with one cell filled with zeros. I think this might not be the best way to set it up, or I have the wrong syntax for the foreach loop.

Comment: try print_r($results), then you'll know easily the indexes and values so then you can go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"num-ASN" is an illegal identifier name. Check what's in `$results`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it so numasn and I get a table but it is only filled with the "numasn" values. Any suggestions? And what did you mean by check what's in $results? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `var_dump($results)` will show you the data structure. You should be able to figure out how to access it.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. I was using the wrong name for the last column and it was the same illegal format so I changed it and the table is populated now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of $results by using

```
 var_dump($results);
```