# Passing custom field to SQL query

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to get user input on 2 questions then use those inputs as part of a SQL query for my wordpress site.

Here is the code I have:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="column_selected">
        <option value="Health Insurance">Health Insurance</option>
        <option value="Education">Education</option>
    </select>
    <select name="state" size="1">
      <option selected value="">State...</option>
      <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="California">California</option>
      <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
      <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
      <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
      <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
      <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
      <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
      <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
      <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
      <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
      <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
      <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
      <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
      <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
      <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
      <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
      <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
      <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
      <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
      <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
      <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
      <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
      <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
      <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
      <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
      <option value="New York">New York</option>
      <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
      <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
      <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
      <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
      <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
      <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
      <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
      <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
      <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
      <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
      <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
      <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
      <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
      <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
      <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
      <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
      <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I then want to use these to run a SQL query on my database and return the results

```
$lotsofasians = ("SELECT '.$column.' FROM bigstatetbl WHERE 'STATE' = '".$state."'"));
```

But I'm pretty sure my SQL query is incorrect and I have a feeling that I need to save the input somehow?

Just for reference my custom table (bigstatetbl) has a column called "STATE" and other columns that match "health insurance" and "education"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is where I am getting stuck after getting the user input:

```
<?php
$column_selected = $_POST["column_selected"];
$state = $_POST["state"];

echo "You have chosen to look at <br> $state <br>";
echo "And Looking at <br> $column_selected";
?>
<?php

$lotsofasians =$wpdb->get_results ("SELECT .$column. FROM 'bigstatetbl' WHERE 'STATE' = '".$state."'"));
echo "$lotsofasians";

?>
```

Comment: If you want to save the input, you need to use the MySQL [`INSERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) function. Something like `$sql = "INSERT INTO bigstatetbl (STATE) VALUES ('$state')";` *"But I'm pretty sure my SQL querry is incorrect and I have a feeling that I need to save the input somehow?"*

Comment: I don't think I want to save the input. I just want to use the user input to run a querry so the user can get a list of results that they want. For example: if the user selected California and Health Insurance the SQL querry would return the results that have those two columns. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, well then you need to loop over the results. Either a `while` or `foreach` loop. Example: `while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) { $states = $row['state'] . "<br>"; echo $states; }`

Comment: Weren't you doing it here => http://stackoverflow.com/q/21761370/ ?

Comment: I'm having trouble just displaying the results of the user input on the same page. When I do
     form action= "" it gives me an error saying there is no url with that name.

Comment: Is your form and SQL on two seperate pages or is everything inside the same page? And all you're showing as far as SQL goes, is just a SELECT. You need to show full code. No sense commenting back & forth.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry! I edited the Q to include the code where I am getting stuck.

Comment: Your code is too prone to SQL injections, http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Comment: use ajax to display the result on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

it should be,

$lotsofasians =$wpdb->get_results ("SELECT ".$column." FROM 'bigstatetbl' WHERE 'STATE' = '".$state."'"));